# AutoHotkey: Timer, label and include

Tags: timer, include, autohotkey

How can I use timers in program, which contains separate files?
Here my example:

**Script1**:

```
#include Script2.ahk
#include Script3.ahk
Timer() 
Hello() 
Exit
```

**Script2**:

```
global variable

Hello(){
    MsgBox, Messsage1
}
```

**Script3**:

```
Timer(){
    SetTimer, Message, 1000
}   

Message:
    MsgBox, Messsage2
    SetTimer, Message, Off
    return
```

This program will instantly show messagebox "Message2" and close.
But I want to get "Message1" and "Message2" one second after the start. Can this be done?

Comment: In script 3, you should add a `return` before the `Message:` label. When you launch script 3 the script will run all the way to the end because there is no return to stop the script from executing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read two links.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm

When you #include files, the contents are simply inserted in the main script at exactly that location. So your Script1 looks like:

```
global variable

Hello(){
    MsgBox, Messsage1
}

Timer(){
    SetTimer, Message, 1000
}   

Message:
    MsgBox, Messsage2
    SetTimer, Message, Off
    return

Timer() 
Hello() 
Exit
```

When the script starts, the auto execute section is run immediately:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto

So everything up to the first return is run (the functions are skipped). Thats why "Message2' shows  immediately and "Message1" is never shown.

Solution:

If you must have the subroutine label within the include file, then you could put the `#include`s at the bottom of the script, after the autoexec section:

```
Timer() 
Hello() 
Exit
#include Script2.ahk
#include Script3.ahk
```

However, it is not good practice to put subroutine labels inside #include files, for this exact reason. Unless of course you understand the consequences mentioned in this post.

Comment: `However, it is not good practice to put subroutine labels inside #include files, for this exact reason.` Which is exactly why AHK needs to allow passing functions to SetTimer instead of only labels.